# Ajax form submission works only once, but I want it to work multiple times

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I'm having issue with form submission in ajax, I have a form and I want to send my data to PHP page via ajax and it works fine for the first time.. but once the first record is added to database, then the Submit button does not work,... for inserting new record I've to refresh my page each time.

Why I've to refresh my page for inserting new record ? how to get rid of from this issue ?
Here is my HTML code:

```
<form id="myForm" action="myInfro.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <label for="name">Book: </label><input type="text" name="name" id="name"><br>
    <label for="name">Author: </label><input type="text" name="author" id="author"><br>
    <input type="hidden" name="insert" id="insert">
    <select id="book_id" name="book_id">
        <option>1</option>
        <option>2</option>
        <option>3</option>
        <option>4</option>
    </select>
    <label for="image">Image: </label><input type="file" name="image" id="image"><br>
    <button id="submit_btn">Insert Data</button>
```

Here is my ajax code:

```
$("#submit_btn").on("click", function(e){
    e.preventDefault();

    $.ajax({
        url:"myInfro.php",
        method:"POST",
        dataType:"text",
        data:$("form").serialize(),
        success:function(data){
            $("#result").html(data).fadeOut(2000);
            $("#myForm")[0].reset();

            load_data();
        }
    });
```

here is my function named load_data() - through which I"m fetching data from the server:

```
function load_data(){
        var load = "load";
        $.ajax({
            url:"myInfro.php",
            method:"POST",
            dataType:"text",
            data:{load:load},
            success:function(data){
                $("#getData").html(data);
            }
        });
    }
```

Comment: What does `load_data()` do?

Comment: load_data() is a function that i've created to fetch data from the database, here in this ajax code I've just called it.... and it works fine, there is no issue with load_data() function,

Comment: OK but does it replace the form (or button)? If so you need to delegate the event listener

Comment: can you elaborate it more please